# Python sqlite: insert values to table with table name being variable

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have some problems to change my code below. I would like to replace the table name with a variable. Any suggestions?

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO budget VALUES (  \
    :date,  \
    :time,  \
    :amount,  \
    :balance,  \
    :balance_EUR  \
    )",  \
    {
     'date': line_list[i*5+0],  \
    'time': line_list[i*5+1], \
    'amount': line_list[i*5+2], \
    'balance': line_list[i*5+3],  \
    'balance_EUR': line_list[i*5+4]  \
    })
```

I tried the code below but that did not work.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO VALUES {} (  \
    :date,  \
    :time,  \
    :amount,  \
    :balance,  \
    :balance_EUR  \
    )".format('table_name'),  \
    {
     'date': line_list[i*5+0],  \
    'time': line_list[i*5+1], \
    'amount': line_list[i*5+2], \
    'balance': line_list[i*5+3],  \
    'balance_EUR': line_list[i*5+4]  \
    })
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string format parameter is at the wrong place in your string. Change it to

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO {} VALUES (  \
    :date,  \
    :time,  \
    :amount,  \
    :balance,  \
    :balance_EUR  \
    )".format('table_name'),  \
    {
     'date': line_list[i*5+0],  \
    'time': line_list[i*5+1], \
    'amount': line_list[i*5+2], \
    'balance': line_list[i*5+3],  \
    'balance_EUR': line_list[i*5+4]  \
    })
```